# Update primary key starting character

Tags: sql, rdbms

I have a table `student` and it has a primary key `student_id`, `student_id` is referred across multiple tables. `student_id` format is `P123X12`

Tables are as follows

- student( student_id is `PK`)
- audit_trail (student_id is `FK`)
- Result( student_id is `FK`)
- more 10 tables which are referring to `student_id`

I have 100 records in Result table, I want to update student_id of those records from `P123X12` to `D123X12`. is there anyway I can change these referred values?

Comment: Could you duplicate your data in student with the new ID, then alter your foreign keys, then finally drop your original values in student?

Comment: all the records are starting with P and I am changing 100 of them with starting from `D` so IDs won't be  duplicate.

Comment: No, but everything else will be, I'll add an answer to explain because it'll be too long for a comment.

Comment: Refer this : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84434/cascade-primary-key-update-to-all-referencing-foreign-keys

Comment: Feel free to add one dbms tag back. (For the product you're using.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, you could duplicate the data in student. Alter your FK fields, then delete the original records from student. You will probably want to tweak the where clause if you're not changing ALL fields that start with a P.

```
/* Duplicate our data in student */
INSERT INTO student (student_id, field2, field3, field4)
SELECT
'D' + SUBSTRING(student_id,2,LEN(student_id)-1)
,field2
,field3
,field4
FROM student
WHERE student_id LIKE 'P%'

/* Update our other tables */
UPDATE audit_trail
SET student_id = 'D' + SUBSTRING(student_id,2,LEN(student_id)-1)
WHERE student_id LIKE 'P%'

UPDATE Result
SET student_id = 'D' + SUBSTRING(student_id,2,LEN(student_id)-1)
WHERE student_id LIKE 'P%'

/* Delete the original rows from student */
DELETE student
WHERE student_id LIKE 'P%'
```

A slightly longer way would be to extract your original fields into a temp table and insert from there. You could then delete from student with an inner join to the temp table to make sure you're only deleting the rows that you definitely want to.

Comment: Some non-ANSI SQL there.  Which dbms?